# Creating a Multivalue ArrayList in java

Tags: java, arraylist

Good day,

I am working on a project for my intro to java class in which we are given 3 .ppm files of the same base image. Each file has had another image inserted in a different place. We are to read the ppm files as text documents and group the values by RGB code.

From there, we are to compare each file's RGB values and select the median value and write the value to the output file. This will, in essence, 'remove' the obstructions from the original images.

I have an Effects class, which within contains a 'filter' method. filter calls 'getEachLine' which feeds, line by line, from each file into the elements of String[] rgbLine. getEachLine calls 'getEachPixel' which is supposed to take the first THREE values and put those three values into an ArrayList. It will then sort the ArrayList, and take the median value to write to output. That writes one pixel.

My question is this: Is there any way to add the first three values of an array's element to a *single* element of an ArrayList? (The final method comparePixel is just an idea right now. I'm trying to make getEachLine and getEachPixel to be properly written first.)

Code provided below:

```
private String getEachLine(){
    for(String[] rgbLine : files[1]){
        lineFeed.nextLine();
    }

    i++;

    for(String[] rgbLine : files[2]){
        lineFeed.nextLine();
    }

    i++;

    for (String[] rgbLine : files[3] ){
        lineFeed.nextLine();
    }
    i++;
    getEachPixel();

    return outputName;

}

private String getEachPixel(rgbLine){
    private ArrayList<String> onePixel = new ArrayList<String>();

    for()
    onePixel.add(files[1].nextInt + files[1].nextInt + 
        files[1].nextInt);
    onePixel.add(files[2].nextInt);
    onePixel.add(files[3].nextInt);

    comparePixel();
}

private int or String comparePixel(ArrayList<String> onePixel){

}
```

Comment: Make a new class with three ints in it, populate it and add that class to the list.

Comment: A list stores instances of a certain type, and  are free to create a type that contains three values. Alternatively you can have three lists in parallel that store one value each (I'd prefer the first version though).

Comment: You can create a list of int arrays of size 3. List<int[]> listOfIntegerArray;

Comment: Please provide the *whole* class, including all the definitions of fields and variables you are using in this code. Also, make sure and post only code that compiles properly.